# Should we include Table Foot Element in a table even if there is no footer in the table?

Tags: html

I read how it is good practice to use `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, and `<thead>` elements whenever using a table for tabular data. Should I still use an empty `<tfoot>` element even if my table does not need a footer at the bottom? Would that be good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, I don't think so you should use `<tfoot>` if there is no use of it...